# Typescript enum type check for conditional types?

Tags: typescript, enums, mapped-types, conditional-types

I have restful services that accept enum values as either the number OR the string, but always return just the number.  Is there a way to type them?

Here's what I kinda want, but it is not syntactically valid:

```
enum Features {
  "A" = 1,
  "B" = 2,
  "C" = 2
}

type EnumOrString<T> = T extends enum
  ? T | keyof T
  : T

declare function getData(featureFilter: EnumOrString<Features>[]): Features[]
```

`getData` takes an array of the enum values or the enum keys but returns only the enum values.

[I also would want to extend this to mapped types like `DeepPartial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20type%20DeepEnumish%3CT%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20T%20extends%20any%5B%5D%20%3F%20DeepEnumishArray%3CT%5Bnumber%5D%3E%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20T%20extends%20enum%20%3F%20T%20%7C%20keyof%20T%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20T%20extends%20object%20%3F%20DeepEnumishObject%3CT%3E%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20DeepEnumishArray%3CT%3E%20extends%20Array%3CDeepEnumish%3CT%3E%3E%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20DeepEnumishObject%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20DeepEnumish%3CT%5BP%5D%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20roundtripPayload(criteria%20%3A%20DeepEnumish%3CPayload%3E)%3A%20Payload) so that any nested enums all get this treatment - without having to have separate hierarchies of types partitioned by Request and Response.

Comment: I don't think you can identify an `enum` programmatically.  The closest I've ever gotten is something like `type IsEnum<T> = T extends Record<keyof T, string | number> ? true : false`, but in any case you'd need to do `EnumOrString<typeof Features>`.

Comment: Wait, so you want something that takes a data structure and recursively changes `Features` to `Features | keyof typeof Features`?

Comment: well, members of *any* enum type (recursively) - but not all members will be enum typed

Comment: requested in https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24293

Comment: There's two parts to this question, then... one which is "identify enums", which I don't think you can do.  The other is "recursively replace an enum type with the union of the enum values and the keys of the enum object", which you *can* do if you know in advance which enums you care about (e.g., `Features`).

Comment: well I'm pretty sure I can make the recursive type that does this given part 1 - I'm just saying that the answer can't cut corners such that part 2 wouldn't be possible.  See the example link in the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the "identify an `enum`" thing is possible right now.  Even if you could, you can't programmatically convert from the `Features` type (which is an *element* of the `Features` enumeration) to the `typeof Features` type (the *mapping* from keys to `Features` elements) without knowing about `Features` in the first place.  Again: the type `Features.B` for example, doesn't know anything about the string literal `"B"`.  Only `typeof Features` has a property like `{B: Features.B}`. If you want a type function to convert from `Features` to `Features | keyof typeof Features`, you need to mention `typeof Features` explicitly.  So even if you had your dream `extends enum` notation, you'd still need to write the replacement code with a list of mappings you care about.  Sorry.

---

Addressing just the recursion part, in case it matters, here's how I'd recursively process a type to replace a *known* enum value with the union of the enum values and the relevant keys:

```
enum Features {
  "A" = 1,
  "B" = 2,
  "C" = 2
}
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]
type FeatureKey<T extends Features> =
  Extract<ValueOf<{
    [K in keyof typeof Features]: [K, typeof Features[K]]
  }>, [any, T]>[0]

type DeepFeaturesOrKey<T> =
  T extends Features ? (T | FeatureKey<T>) :
  T extends Array<infer L> ? DeepFeaturesOrKeyArray<L> :
  T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: DeepFeaturesOrKey<T[K]> } : T

interface DeepFeaturesOrKeyArray<L> extends Array<DeepFeaturesOrKey<L>> { }
```

The tricky bits are extracting a subset of the enum if you don't specify the whole thing (e.g., you're using a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) keyed off a specific enum value), and of course, the whole deep-whatever Array trickery to avoid the dreaded "circular reference" error message mentioned [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316#issue-164138025):

> Similar to union and intersection types, conditional types are not permitted to reference themselves recursively (however, indirect references through interface types or object literal types are allowed)

Let's test it:

```
interface Foo {
  bar: string,
  baz: Features,
  qux: {
    a: Features[],
    b: boolean
  },
  quux: Features.A,
  quuux: Features.B  
}

type DeepFeaturesOrKeyFoo = DeepFeaturesOrKey<Foo>
declare const deepFeaturesOrKeyFoo: DeepFeaturesOrKeyFoo
deepFeaturesOrKeyFoo.bar; // string
deepFeaturesOrKeyFoo.baz; // Features | "A" | "B" | "C"
deepFeaturesOrKeyFoo.qux.a[1];  // Features | "A" | "B" | "C"
deepFeaturesOrKeyFoo.qux.b; // boolean
deepFeaturesOrKeyFoo.quux; // Features.A | "A"
deepFeaturesOrKeyFoo.quuux; // Features.B | "B" | "C" 
// note that the compiler considers Features.B and Features.C to be the
// same value, so this becomes Features.B | "B" | "C"
```

Looks good.  Hope that helps.